# Using a RESTful API for Dynamic Websites

Tags: php, mysql, rest

**PHP and MySQL**

In building dynamic websites (can be personal, web app, etc..), is it suitable to use API request calls, instead of MySQL queries?

Example in my function `getArticles()`, should I use a native MySQL query like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT id, title, content
        FROM r_articles'
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('.. bla bla');
```

Or, just execute a GET request to: `http://mysite.com/api/articles`. Then (supposed to be the response is in JSON) format the response.

**NOTE:** The API of course is to be created first.

Comment: I'm late to the party, I know, but wouldn't your REST-approach lead to twice as many HTTP requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends fully on the type of your site.
If you're building a small project with just the webinterface, stay with your mysql calls.

If you're doing a site which shall grow big and serve more than one service, e.g. an android/iPhone application is already planned out, build the api and let both applications use it.
APIs are great for scalability and serving to a lot of customers.
However, for a web representation e.g. for your locals dentist its simply overhead.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

I think a lot of that depends on the application.  If the application is expected to be widely deployed (through the enterprise / etc.) such that more than one site would need access to the same objects that this application does, querying a web service for your Article object would probably lead to cleaner, more reusable code.

At the same time, I'd argue that there's some additional work involved engineering and implementing that kind of a solution, and further some additional overhead involved in making the additional GET requests from the PHP script to do that kind of processing.  Additionally, there could be security risks involved with making an external interface like this available that may need to be examined.

Thus, my recommendation would be to keep objects nicely encapsulated and build them with SQL if the site is local and / or small (since there's always the option of offering them up via SOAP or JSON or what have you later, if you do it right :).  If, on the other hand, this is going to be a larger-scale, distributed application, then I'd vote for spending the time at the beginning to build some kind of service framework API thingamajig, since you'll probably need it later.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find this method to be pretty awesome. If you know you will be using that API in the future, it ensures you that your API has the same functionality as the website and consolidates all your logic. The disadvantage is that you probably will have a bit of extra overhead.

P.S. Depending on the anticipated size of your service/website, you might wanna put that API on its on subdomain (api.website.com).