# Build many websites based in a single RESTful API, how should I do?

Tags: rest

I'm building a RESTful API (in PHP using [Restler Framework v3.0](http://luracast.com/products/restler/)) and I'm so confusing about what are the best pratices of how to use it.

I want to use the Rest API to authenticate users in more than one domain (same users, many domains) and get some "global" info (eg.: latest blog posts), but I have this questions.

#### My Questions:

1. Should I use REST instead of database queries?
2. Should I use the API only for XHR requests?

---

**EDIT:** I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689060/using-a-restful-api-for-dynamic-websites) that is like mine.

I want to build websites using the same users, get "latest posts", etc... If I make the REST API I could use it to get the users instead of querying database and duplicating code.

Comment: I edited my question to explain better.

Comment: That question still does not make sense. It's like asking "should I eat a sandwich instead of reading a book?"

Comment: No, I think I'm not explaining it right... I'll try here. I can get my latest posts from the rest (eg.: api.domain.com/posts/latest) or I can fetch it from the database (eg.: 'SELECT * FROM ...'). Which is better way to fetch results? Which is faster? How would you do it?

Comment: you can hide all your queries under server classes and expose them as REST apis , just for clarity and re-usability